# How to pass join key as variable in Spark Data Frame using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to kep the join key of the two dataframe in two varibale. The same i want to pass into a join . here My variable contains one key. Can I also pass more than one key ?

Ex: 
**1st key :**
scala> val primary_key_col = scd_table_keys_df.first().getString(2)
primary_key_col: String = acct_nbr

**2nd key :**
scala> val delta_primary_key_col = "delta_"+primary_key_col
delta_primary_key_col: String = delta_acct_nbr

```
** My python Code which is working
cdc_new_acct_df = delta_src_rename_df.join(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df ,(col(delta_primary_key_col) == col(primary_key_col)) ,'left_outer' ).where(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df[primary_key_col].isNull())
```

I want to achieve same in Scala. Please suggest.
Tries multiple ways.

```
val cdc_new_acct_df = delta_src_rename_df.join(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df ,(delta_src_rename_df({primary_key_col.mkstring(",")}) == hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df({primary_key_col.mkstring(",")}),"left_outer" )).where(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df[primary_key_col].isNull())
```

:121: error: value mkstring is not a member of String

```
val cdc_new_acct_df = delta_src_rename_df.join(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df ,(delta_src_rename_df(delta_primary_key_col.map(c => col(c))) == hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df(primary_key_col.map(c => col(c))),"left_outer" ))
```

:123: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]
 required: String

Not able to solve. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the variable substitution. This is working for me.

```
scala> val cdc_new_acct_df = delta_src_rename_df.join(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df ,delta_src_rename_df(**s"$delta_primary_key_col"**) === hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df(s"$primary_key_col"),"left_outer" )
    cdc_new_acct_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [delta_acct_nbr: string, delta_primary_state: string, delta_zip_code: string, delta_load_tm: string, delta_load_date: string, hash_key_col: string, delta_hash_key: int, delta_eff_start_date: string, acct_nbr: string, account_sk_id: bigint, primary_state: string, zip_code: string, eff_start_date: string, eff_end_date: string, load_tm: string, hash_key: string, eff_flag: string]
```